# How to fix " Error in script (event chat): TypeError: Cannot access member 'indexOf' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I found this abandoned script for a teamspeak bot that i wanted to get working. i never really worked with javascript ever, so i'm hoping someone out there will be able to help me.

When i try to run the script the following error is given in the instance log.

"Error in script (event chat): TypeError: Cannot access member 'indexOf' of undefined at cleverbot.js:76:13"

I've tried contacting the author, and i've asked for help on the forum where i found the script.

```
event.on('chat', function(ev) {
    var client = ev.clientId;        
    var mode = ev.mode;

    if (ev.mode == 0 || ev.mode == 3) return;
    if (ev.msg.indexOf("Cleverbot,") === 0 || ev.msg.indexOf("@cleverbot") === 0) {
        var question = ev.msg.substring(11, ev.msg.length);
        sinusbot.http({
            "method": "POST", 
            "url": "https://cleverbot.io/1.0/ask", 
            "timeout": 60000,
            "body": "user=" + apiuser + "&key=" + apikey +
                "&nick=" + sinusbot.getBotId() + "&text=" + encodeURI(question),
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        }, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                sinusbot.log(error);
                return;
            }

            var data = JSON.parse(response.data);                
            if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                sinusbot.chatChannel(data.status);
                return;
            }

            var response = data.response;
            if (mode == 1) {
                sinusbot.chatPrivate(client, response);
            } 
            else if (mode == 2) {
                sinusbot.say(response, lang);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'ev' param has no such msg property so the indexOf is failing (no string)

```js
...
ev.msg.indexOf
...
```

Try to debug your code to double check why is this happening